# consume web service from mvc website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

If I have exposed web service on address http://localhost:45185/GetData/ which accepts 3 paramteres  `{MyString}/{Date1}/{ToDate}`

how can I restfully consume this service from mvc controller action?

p.s. webservice is exposed using servicestack (if this is important at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a code snippet like this if your params can be passed as querystring to the service:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:45185/GetData?MyString=test&Date1=test&ToDate=test");
    }
```

If they are part of the route in the service this could work:

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:45185/GetData/test/test/test");
        }
```

Comment: Where HttpClient class resides? I dont have it under System.Net namespace?

Comment: @user1765862 it is in System.Net.Http

Comment: using any of this two solutions I'm getting status of web service response as waiting for activation.

Answer (score 0):

If the Web Service is exposed using ServiceStack than you can just use a [ServiceStack .NET Service Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) and the Remote Server DTO .dll or you can generate the remote servers DTO's on the client using [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/CSharp-Add-ServiceStack-Reference) which will let you consume ServiceStack Services with a strong typed API, e.g:

```
var response = client.Get(new GetData { MyString = mystr });
```

Comment: thank you. having my service details request how would define a client for asp.net mvc web ap? Can you please provide more detail example.

Comment: @user1765862 Check out the links above, you can use any of the ServiceStack Service Clients where you just need to provide the Base URL where ServiceStack instance is hosted, e.g: `var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUri);`